# Laravel Eloquent and setTable() in relashionships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use settable() method and get the data from relashionship. Here are my Models:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function list(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\List');
    }
}
class List extends Model
{
    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

In the Controller, I set the table before the select:

```
$this->list->setTable("user_".auth()->user()->id."_lists");
$users = $this->list->where('order_id', $id)->with('Order')->get();
```

The problem is: the setTable() method can set the list table correctly, but how can I set the orders table correctly, since the with() method only gets the default orders table? Example: the orders table should be user_{$id}*orders and the lists table shoud be user*{$id}_lists

Answer (score 1):

To be honest for me it doesn't make any point. When you have 1000 users, you will have 1000 tables for orders and 1000 tables for lists? You should rather rethink your database design.

Comment: I'm using multi-tenancy from orchestra package. This will not have a lot of users as expected.

Comment: @Clayton It's still bad practise. Would never recommend.

Comment: What is the best practice for this case?